# Inner Joins on 3 tables how to get the Id of the max values of a date?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query:

```
SELECT CON_ID, CON_CreatedBy, COM_DateTime FROM CON_Conversation
    INNER JOIN COU_ConversationUser AS cu USING (CON_ID)
    INNER JOIN COM_ConversationMessage AS cm USING (CON_ID)
WHERE cu.USR_ID = 4328 AND cm.USR_ID = 4328
ORDER BY CON_ID DESC
```

And this is my result:
[image]

Now I would like to return only the CON_Ids that have the MAX COM_DateTime.
How can I do this??

Comment: you want the MAX COM_DateTime for a specific CON_id or for all the Ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subselect should work for you:

```
select CON_ID, max(COM_DateTime)
from
(
    SELECT CON_ID, COM_DateTime 
    FROM CON_Conversation
    INNER JOIN COU_ConversationUser AS cu USING (CON_ID)
    INNER JOIN COM_ConversationMessage AS cm USING (CON_ID)
    WHERE cu.USR_ID = 4328 AND cm.USR_ID = 4328
    ORDER BY CON_ID DESC
) as sub
group by CON_ID
ORDER BY max(COM_DateTime) DESC
```

Comment: That query also returns the rows that do not have the overall `MAX COM_DateTime`.

Comment: @FabianBarney This query will return the con_id and its max time.  If there is more than one record for the con_id only the max time will be returned.  That's my interpretation of OP's request.

Comment: @paqogomez Thanks1!! You just missed at the end the ORDER BY MAX(COM_DateTime) DESC

Comment: @Monica, great, glad I could help.  I'll edit the post with those changes.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that clear what you're asking. As I understood your question you want something like "latest `con_id`", right?!

```
SELECT CON_ID FROM CON_Conversation
    INNER JOIN COU_ConversationUser AS cu USING (CON_ID)
    INNER JOIN COM_ConversationMessage AS cm USING (CON_ID)
WHERE cu.USR_ID = 4328 AND cm.USR_ID = 4328
ORDER BY COM_DateTime DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The query gives you the `con_id` for the max(COM_DateTime). It's ordered by `COM_DateTime` and only keeping the first row and returning its `con_id`.

I am assuming that it is ok to just have returned any `con_id` for the case when having multiple rows with identical max(COM_DateTime).

Comment: This would return a single row with the max date and give the one `CON_ID`.  I believe when the OP says `return only the CON_Ids` (notice the plural) they are looking for more than one record.

Comment: that can never happen. SO that is why won't work. :(

Comment: @paqogomez I realized the plural but also the the second part of the sentence "that have the MAX COM_DateTime". The question is not that clear.